# How to clear swap

Tags: swap

how do I clear the swap? I know it isn't something that is needed, but I still want to know how to do it.
this is what I'm doing so far:

```bsh
# to check if there is enough space in ram for the swap contents:
free -m
```

```bsh
sudo swapoff -a
sudo chmod 600 /var/swap
sudo mkswap /var/swap
sudo swapon -a
```

that works for clearing the swap, but it doesn't turn on again because it isn't being used until I reboot.

Comment: What turns off swap is `swapoff -a`. Since you already know that I'm not clear what it is that you're asking

Comment: @roaima first of all my question is how to clear it.
and when I turn it back on it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you asking "why does swap not turn on after clearing it? Am I doing it right? I want to clear it then continue using it."

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes, that's exactly what I'm asking.
I already got a answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Without `systemd`**

You can disable swap with `swapoff -a`. If swap is being used it is not an instantaneous action (see `man swapoff`).

If you have defined swap in `/etc/fstab` you can use `swapon -a` to activate all known swap files and partitions. If none is defined there you need to declare the swap space that you want to use, for example `swapon /var/swap`.

There is no need to recreate it each time you want to use it

**2. With `systemd`**

The new method for activating swap is through a `systemd` service, run at boot. You can see its status, for example,

```
systemctl status dphys-swapfile     # What happened last time it ran
systemctl restart dphys-swapfile    # Recompute the swapfile space and reactivate it
```

In turn, `systemd` calls the `dphys-swapfile` command (see `man dphys-swapfile`), which computes a reasonably sized swapfile partition and activates it, or deactivates it, as required.

For example,

```
dphys-swapfile swapoff    # Stop using the swapfile
dphys-swapfile setup      # (Re-)compute an optimal swap space as /var/swap
dphys-swapfile swapon     # Start using the computed swapfile
```

In the `systemd` and `dphys-swapfile` world, swapspace defaults to the file `/var/swap` rather than a partition

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there. Before clearing swap, you must unmount it first. In most cases, swap is already defined in the `/etc/fstab` file. Follow these steps to avoid rebooting your system:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo umount /var/swap
sudo chmod 600 /var/swap
sudo mkswap /var/swap
sudo swapon -a
sudo mount -a
```

Comment: Swap isn't a mountable filesystem

Comment: Swap can be mounted. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-mount-swap-partition-107923/

Comment: You're misunderstanding that article. Swap is not a mountable filesystem